# Calling Unittest++ from cmake created makefile

Tags: cmake

I recently started learning cmake, and have run into a small issue.  I got both my executable and the unit tests to compile from the generated makefile without issue.  If I run `./test` in the build directory, the tests created in UnitTest++ run and complete as expected, printing the results.  Is there any way to get `make test` to simply run the test executable rather than running it inside ctest framework or should I go about this a different way?

Here is a minimal working example of my code:

src/main/main.c is a simple empty main function

src/test/testMain.cpp:

```
#include <UnitTest++/UnitTest++.h>

TEST(FailSpect)
{
    CHECK(false);
}

int main()
{
    UnitTest::RunAllTests();
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.6 )
project( myProject)

enable_testing()

set( myProjectMain
    src/main/main.c
    )

set( myProjectSrc
    )

set( myProjectTestSrc
    src/test/testMain.cpp
    )

add_executable( myExecutable ${myProjectMain} ${myProjectSrc} )
add_executable( testSuite ${myProjectTestSrc} ${myProjectSrc} )

target_link_libraries( testSuite UnitTest++ )

add_test( testExe testSuite )
```

`make test` output:

```
Running tests...
Start processing tests
Test project /myProjectDir/build
  1/  1 Testing testExe                       Passed

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 1
```

`./testSuite` output:

```
/myProjectDir/src/test/testMain.cpp:5: error: Failure in FailSpect: false
FAILURE: 1 out of 1 tests failed (1 failures).
Test time: 0.00 seconds.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out how to do this.  First remove the lines:

```
enable_testing()
```

and

```
add_test(testExe testSuite)
```

and replace them by the line:

```
add_custom_target(test ./testExe
    DEPENDS ./testExe)
```

at the end of the CMakeLists.txt file.  Now `make (all)` builds both the tests and the main program.  If everything is built already, then `make test` will just check that the tests are built and run them, producing:

```
[100%] Built target testExe
/myProjectDir/src/test/testMain.cpp:5: error: Failure in FailSpect: false
FAILURE: 1 out of 1 tests failed (1 failures).
Test time: 0.00 seconds.
[100%] Built target test
```

If the tests are out of date (after a `make clean` for instance), then `make test` will produce:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/testExe.dir/src/test/testMain.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable testExe
[100%] Built target testExe
/myProjectDir/src/test/testMain.cpp:5: error: Failure in FailSpect: false
FAILURE: 1 out of 1 tests failed (1 failures).
Test time: 0.00 seconds.
[100%] Built target test
```